# How to find the distance to the nearest coastline from Property Place latitude/longitude point?

Tags: php, google-maps

I have one place with latitude and longitude. I would like to find nearest sea coast distance miles/km to my place using google Map API.

Is this any solutions regarding this in php?

More Descriptions:

Is there anyway to know the distance to the nearest sea coast point (that is the minimun distance from the sea)?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Have a look at your CAPS-lock button. What have you tried/found already?

Comment: IM NoT  SURE but I think THIs guy neeDS soME hELP using StaCKOVerflow. We won't GIVE you any coDE. MAke an ATTEMPT

Comment: what is wrong in my comment

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. Your question seems to get received badly by the community. This is, because your question is really broad. Questions like *Is this any solutions* or *Is it possible in PHP* are conceptual *yes/no* questions and show an unwillingness of research. Yet, the correct order is to do your research first and ask a quastion once you hit a bug that you seem to can not fix.

Answer (score 2):

Please try

```
$dist = "https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/directions/json?key=&origin=".$lat1.",".$lon1."&destination=".$lat2.",".$lon2."&mode=driving&sensor=true";
$result_string = file_get_contents($dist);
$result = json_decode($result_string, true);
```

Comment: thanks but its not useful , I Find Cost line Distance Miles/km To My place here we don't have cost line destinations lat and long

Answer (score 0):

Use this function to calculate distance between long and lat

> ```
> function distance($lat1, $lon1, $lat2, $lon2, $unit) {
>
>   $theta = $lon1 - $lon2;
>   $dist = sin(deg2rad($lat1)) * sin(deg2rad($lat2)) +  cos(deg2rad($lat1)) * cos(deg2rad($lat2)) * cos(deg2rad($theta));
>   $dist = acos($dist);
>   $dist = rad2deg($dist);
>   $miles = $dist * 60 * 1.1515;
>   $unit = strtoupper($unit);
>
>   if ($unit == "K") {
>     return ($miles * 1.609344);
>   } else if ($unit == "N") {
>       return ($miles * 0.8684);
>     } else {
>         return $miles;
>       }
> }
>
> echo distance(32.9697, -96.80322, 29.46786, -98.53506, "M") . " Miles<br>";
> echo distance(32.9697, -96.80322, 29.46786, -98.53506, "K") . " Kilometers<br>";
> echo distance(32.9697, -96.80322, 29.46786, -98.53506, "N") . " Nautical Miles<br>";
> ```

Comment: thanks but its not useful , I Find Cost line Distance Miles/km To My place here we don't have cost line lat and long

Answer (score 0):

There's a Distance to Coast REST API: http://www.kbgeo.com. You provide a target latitude/longitude pair or street address and it returns distance to the nearest coastal point and what that point is.
Example JSON response:

```
{
  "distanceInMiles": 702.4893212372758,
  "targetPoint": {
    "lat": 43.045583,
    "lng": -89.3799951
  },
  "coastlinePoint": {
    "lat": 38.662389,
    "lng": -77.236111
  }
}
```

There's a live demo page at http://demo.kbgeo.com.

**Disclosure:** I wrote this API and therefore have a vested interest. Another API that does the same thing is maprisk.com.

Comment: Ludovico, as I explained in response to your messages at kbgeo.com and my personal website, KB Geo Distance to Coast calculates distance from a point on land to the nearest sea coast. It does not calculate distance from a point in the water to the nearest land. This is not a bug - it's the way the product is designed. You will need to find another product or write your own in order to solve your use case.